# UIView Animation in SKScene

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

UIView Animation isn't working in SKScene

MyScene.h

```
@property (nonatomic) SKLabelNode *tutorialLabel;
```

MyScene.m

```
- (IBAction)hideLabel:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^(void) {
        [_tutorialLabel setAlpha:0.0];
    }];
}
```

Is there a better way to hide an SKLabelNode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fade out the label, you can use SKActions:

```
- (IBAction)hideLabel:(id)sender {
    [_tutorialLabel runAction:[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:1.0f]];
}
```